# 5 balls of different colors are to be placed in 3 different boxes (each box contains atleast 1 ball) What is the number of ways of doing this?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I worked it out as 3,1,1 arrangements and 2,2,1 arrangements for each of the three boxes and their respective combinations. Getting it to be 150 ways in total. But this is a kind of a long method. Would there be a shorter and better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Inclusion/Exclusion.  That  can also be computationally tedious. But for this type of problem it works very nicely.

There are $3^5$ functions from the set of balls to the set of boxes, that is, $3^5$ assignments of boxes to the balls.

We must take away the *bad* functions, the functions that fail the "at least one in each box" condition.

So let us remove the $2^5$ functions that leave a box A empty. Do the same for B and C. So we remove $\binom{3}{1}2^5$.

But we have removed too many times the functions that leave two boxes empty. For in the previous step we removed twice, for example, the functions that leave A and B empty. The same thing happened for every pair of boxes.  So we must pit back $\binom{3}{2}1^5$.  We end up with
$$3^5-\binom{3}{1}2^5+\binom{3}{2}1^5.$$

Comment: :If the balls were identical only then we could use the "Stars and Bars" approach right? How did you get 2^5 in your solution? @André Nicolas

Comment: If the balls were identical, then yes it is standard Stars and Bars. As to your second question, how many ways are there to put the balls into boxes A and/or B? This is the number of functions from a $5$ element set to a $2$ element set, same as the idea that got us $3^5$.

Comment: Well, I have never worked with "functions" in combinatorics. So am a little lost here. Is there a link where I can read up on the basics of this method? That would be very helpful. Thanks. @André Nicolas

Comment: Can't think of a link. But suppose we have $n$ distinct balls,and $k$ bins. Want to count the number of ways to put balls into bins, no restriction. The location of Ball $1$ can be chosen in $k$ ways. For each way, there are $k$ ways to place Ball $2$, and so on for a total of $k^n$.  A way of placing all the balls can be thought of as a function $f$. where $f(i)$ tells us which bin Ball $i$ goes into.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, your answers are always pretty easy and quite elaborate! You have made internet the best place to learn mathematics!

Answer (score 2):

> Would there be a shorter and better way to do it?

Behold the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind):

$$ 3! \ S(5,3) = 6 \times 25 = 150 $$

The factor $3!$ appears here because the Stirling numbers of the second kind count the combinations considering the boxes are unlabelled (undistinguishable).